# Firefox Extension Development: Adding Tabs to the Preference Pane?

Tags: firefox-addon, xul

I'm adding this:

```
   <prefwindow id="BrowserPreferences">
      <!-- Create a new pane (tab)  -->
      <prefpane id="whateverPrefs" label="yes!" 
      onpaneload="alert('hey')" 
                image="chrome://helloworld/content/images/man.png">

        <!-- Intermediary between GUI and preferences system -->
        <preferences>
           <!-- see the next section for more information -->
        </preferences>

        <!-- GUI Elements... -->
      </prefpane>
    </prefwindow>
```

to my overlay.xul. It doesn't work whatsoever, though it is suggested [here](http://www.rietta.com/firefox/Tutorial/prefs.html). I do have wonderful success with this code, though:

```
  <menupopup id="menu_ToolsPopup">
    <menuitem id="helloworld-hello2" label="frigger!" 
              oncommand="HelloWorld.onMenuItemCommand(event);"/>
  </menupopup>
```

Is this a version problem (e.g., Firefox 3.x will not do it)? I am unable to find the string BrowserPreferences in browser.xul, which seems to be part of the problem. How can I add tabs to the preference pane in Firefox?

[Sorry if this question is really simple, but searching for help on Firefox Extensions is like searching for help on the word "is."]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your code is wrong, but it should be overlaying preferences.xul not browser.xul - I'm guessing your overlay is registering with browser.xul and that's why your menu item works fine.

Check the section 'Register an Overlay' about half way down the MDC article [Building an Extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Building_an_Extension)

Comment: Excellent, I'll do that forthwith and report back... I mean tomorrow, it's 3am here :) THANKS.

Comment: Apparently I have to "get reading" on that MDC article. I'll mark this best answer when I get some stuff working. Thanks again.

Comment: That worked, thanks for your help and for insisting on the MDC docs.

Comment: Glad it worked out.  I always tend start with the MDC stuff as it seems at least to get kept up to date.